# Constructing and Destructing an object

Tags: c++

Here i wanted to observe how copy constructor works.In function my_fun test t1 is constructed and passed by value to t object. After passing the t1, the t object have to construct by using "copy constructor" but its not happening here and also the t1 object is not destructing after copying t1 to t.why its happening like this??

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class test{
    public:
        int a;
        test()
        {
            cout<<"constructor=="<<this<<"\n";
        }
        test(const test& t)
        {
            cout<<"copy cosntructor=="<<this<<"\n"; 
        }
        ~test()
        {
            cout<<"destructor=="<<this<<"\n";
        }
};
test my_fun(test t)
{
    cout<<"hello\n";
    test t1;
    return t1;
}
main()
{
    test ob1;
    test t=my_fun(ob1);
    cout<<"im ok";
}

output:
constructor==0x6ffdf0
copy cosntructor==0x6ffe00
hello
constructor==0x6ffde0
destructor==0x6ffe00
im okdestructor==0x6ffde0
destructor==0x6ffdf0
```

Comment: "but its not happening here" unclear what you mean. The copy constructor is appearing in the output. Please add both, actual and expected output

Comment: Where did you define the `fun` function?

Comment: The concepts you're missing are "copy elision" and "return value optimization". The subject is a bit large for this Q&A format.

Comment: You declared the function `my_fun` and called the function `fun`. How did you get any output except for an compile time error?

Comment: Didn't you get at least a warning for `main()`?

Comment: The code passes two different objects around, and that can easily become confusing. To make it easer to see what's going on, change `my_fun` to `void my_fun(test t)` and get rid of `t1`. Once you see what's going on there, change it again, to `test my_fun();`, put `t1` back in, and call it with no arguments.

Comment: @PeteBecker I tried those things and I understood what was happening there. but here in this code the t is have to construct using copy constructor and print "copy constructor" but here its not printing it why?

Answer (score 0):

```
test my_fun(test t) <-- the "t" object is never used
{
    cout<<"hello\n";
    test t1;  <-- you create a new object "t1"
    test t2(t); <-- if you want the copy constructor to be called you need to call it
    return t1; <-- you return that object
-- the t object is destroyed here since it has gone out of scope --
}
main()
{
    test ob1; <-- You create this object
    test t=my_fun(ob1); <-- Copy constructor is called to pass this object to this function since you are passing by value not reference. 
    cout<<"im ok";
}
```